# Duplicate Product Group Price

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-group, group-price

I have an error after a recent update to Magento 1.9.3.1 when I try to save a product in a specific storeview.

It only happens with products where the group-price is set like this:[image]

It seems to me the group-price is set correctly like this. Anyway, before the upgrade it worked. 
The solution could be to add the group-price in every website separately, but that would be a lot of work.

Is this common behaviour or a bug? Anyone experienced the same or knows a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue after upgrade to 1.9.3.2. I think it's a core bug that is related to the new group price attribute **is_percent**. Here is a hotfix that I use:

EDITED:

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/price/group.phtml`:

```
    if (data.readOnly == '1') {
        // EDIT: added 'is_percent' to disabled fields
        ['website', 'cust_group', 'price', 'delete', 'is_percent'].each(function(element_suffix) {
            $('group_price_row_' + data.index + '_' + element_suffix).disabled = true;
        });
        $('group_price_row_' + data.index + '_delete_button').hide();
    }
```

Comment: That works! Thank you.
Hopefully Magento will change it soon.

Comment: Your solution works for me too. and saved my lot of time.